# How do i check that an array contains values of an object

Tags: javascript

Lets say that we have an object like:

```
{"A":["00002","00003","00004"]}
```

and an array:

```
["00002", "00003"]
```

What i am trying to do is check Objects values and if that keys values are not all existing in array alert user that key A values are not all existed in array.

What if A is unknown ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate through object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `.filter` on the array and check if all the values exists in another array or not.

```js
var obj = {"A":["00002","00003","00004"]}
var check = ["00002", "00003"];

if(obj.A.filter(el => !check.includes(el)).length){
  console.log("Some elements does not exists");
}
```

**Update: If you dont know what the key is:**

There could be multiple ways, the one I would is to use `Object.values(obj)[0]` to access the array.

```js
var obj = {"A":["00002","00003","00004"]}
var check = ["00002", "00003"];

if(Object.values(obj)[0].filter(el => !check.includes(el)).length){
  console.log("Some elements does not exists");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by you don't know A? You dont know what the key is or you dont know whether it exists or not?

Comment: we dont know what the key is

Comment: this is working but i had property filter does not exist on type {}error i am using typescript do you know why ?

Comment: Property 'filter' does not exist on type '{}'.

Answer (score 0):

You should retrieve the array inside the object:

```
object.A
```

Next you need to loop through the array you want to check

```
var allMatch = true;
var object = {"A":["00002","00003","00004"]};
["00002", "00003"].forEach(function(item){
    if(object.A.indexOf(item) === -1){ // -1 when not found
        allMatch = false;
    }
});

alert("Do they all match? " + allMatch);
```

Or if you need Old Internet Explorer support.

```
var allMatch = true;
var object = {"A":["00002","00003","00004"]};
var arr = ["00002", "00003"];
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(object.A.indexOf(arr[i]) === -1){ // -1 when not found
        allMatch = false;
        break; // Stop for loop, since it is false anyway
    }
};

alert("Do they all match? " + allMatch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop them and check..

```js
var haystack = {"A":["00002","00003","00004"]};
var needle = ["00002", "00003"];

function allItemsExist(h, n){
  for(var k in h) if(!~n.indexOf(h[k])) return false;
  return true;
}

if(!allItemsExist(haystack.A, needle)) alert("something is missing");
else alert("everything is here");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function containsAllData(obj, key, arr)
{
   if(arr.length < obj[key].length)
   {
      alert("Array is not fully contained!");
      return false;
   }
   for(var i = 0; i < obj[key].length; i++)
      if(arr[i] !== obj[key][i])
      {   
         alert("Array contains different data!");
         return false;
      }
   return true;
}
```